# Default File Manager is not showing up in intent chooser

Tags: android

I am programming for picking up Image|PDF as below

```
private void openImageChooser() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
    String[] mimeTypes = {"image/*", "application/pdf"};
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        if (mimeTypes.length > 0) {
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);
        }
    } else {
        String mimeTypesStr = "";
        for (String mimeType : mimeTypes) {
            mimeTypesStr += mimeType + "|";
        }
        intent.setType(mimeTypesStr.substring(0, mimeTypesStr.length() - 1));
    }

    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    String pickTitle = "Select Picture or PDF"; // Or get from strings.xml
    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, pickTitle);

    startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, CHOOSE_FILE);
}
```

**Problem** : In some Android devices, Default File manager Option is not showing up in chooser. Is there any way to handle such case ?

Comment: thats how the different OS behaves you cannot handle all

Answer (score 0):

> Problem : In some Android devices, Default File manager Option is not showing up in chooser

I would not expect a file manager to show up for `ACTION_PICK` for the `MediaStore`.

> Is there any way to handle such case ?

Start by getting rid of the MIME type. [`ACTION_PICK` does not use a MIME type](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK), whether set via `setDataAndType()` or `EXTRA_MIME_TYPES`.

Alternatively you could switch to `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` or `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`, which *do* use MIME types (but do not usually use a `Uri`).

In either case, though, there is no requirement for every app that you think should show up to actually show up. What implicit `Intents` an app supports is up to the developers of that app, not you.

Comment: Can't switch to ACTION_GET_CONTENT for Multiple selection.

Comment: Kindly Do check code, I have used EXTRA_MIME_TYPES for greater than HONEYCOMB versions.

Comment: @LostGeek: If you read [the documentation for `ACTION_PICK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PICK) and [the documentation for `EXTRA_MIME_TYPES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_MIME_TYPES), you will learn that `ACTION_PICK` does not use `EXTRA_MIME_TYPES`. `ACTION_GET_CONTETN` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` do.

Comment: Yes noticed that, but practically it was working partially. Anyways, Thank you for your time and suggestion , I ended up choosing ACTION_GET_CONTENT and some workaround :)